# set javascript validation based on condition

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I m trying to check whether username is exits in db or not. If exits than it should give error msg and prevent the user to add details into db till they edit the user field or make it valid or available.
Ajax Call

```
$('#user').keyup(function(e) {
    var check_user=$(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        url: "ajax.php",
        data: {check_user:check_user},
        success: function(data)
        {   
            $("#user-result").html(data);

        }
    });         
});
```

Ajax.php

```
if(isset($_POST['check_user'])){    
$class->mqry="AND barcode='".$_POST['check_user']."' ";
$class->selected_fields=array('this.user_id');
$check_user= $class->getTable('users'); 
$class->resetFields();
$count=count($check_user);
if($count) {
    die('<img src="imgs/not-available.png" />User already exits');
}else{
    die('<img src="imgs/available.png" />');
}

}
```

This things are working.Now how can I prevent user to add details.I wan to set validation for this user field.I hope this make sence.

Here I just take user example. In real There will be details like barcode etc...

Comment: Am I correct in understanding that you send an Ajax-request every time a key is pressed inside the username input field?

Comment: Why? That seems a little intensive.

Comment: **warning** i see a potential sql injection attack!

Comment: @Kreya - Wow, ok, I wouldn't do that. I would let the user first enter the full name, and then with a button/enter let them submit that username (and if you have more inputfields, first let them enter all fields and then submit.) This is very inefficient.

Comment: are you trying to add client side validation for data - there are numerous validation libraries available (with or without jquery) and you can write it in javascript on your own as well.Parsleyjs is one.

Comment: @DanielA.White: How sql injection is attack  ?

Comment: this line: `$class->mqry="AND barcode='".$_POST['check_user']."' ";`

Comment: @alihaider : Yes I m trying to add client side validation. I dont know how can I link this ajax call to query validation

Comment: @Kreya look up these functions: mysql_real_escape_string() and htmlspecialchars()

Comment: you need to use client side validation before you send the ajax - if validation on client side passes, then send ajax and register your callbacks.  Also, perform validation on server side as well and do not rely on client side validation only.

Comment: @DanielA.White : What is alternative options?

Comment: @kreya so how do a parameterized query, not string concatenation

Answer (score 0):

You need to use client side validation before you send the ajax - if validation on client side passes, then send ajax and register your callbacks.  Also, perform validation on server side as well and do not rely on client side validation only.  Parsleyjs is one option - you can use jquery validation as well or roll own your own (probably best to use a good third party validation library).